# Deserialize JSON Object to User Defined Type

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON Object which is like

```json
[
    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "M2O_ProductOptions__c",
            "url": ""
        },
        "Id": "aAP8A0000004ZkiWAE",
        "ExternalId__c": "123456_ABCDEFG",
        "Product__r": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Product2",
                "url": "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Product2"
            },
            "ProductCode": "123456"
        },
        "Option__r": {
            "attributes": {
                "type": "Product2",
                "url": "/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/"
            },
            "ProductCode": "23456"
        }
    }
]
```

And I have classes

```
public class SF_M20_ProductOptions
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId__c { get; set; }
    public Product__r Product__r { get; set; }
    public Option__r Option__r { get; set; }
}

public class Product__r
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
}

public class Option__r
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to deserialize the JSON string to the type `SF_M20_ProductOptions`, but I am getting an error.

> Unable to convert type string to SF_M20_ProductOptions

**Note**: `"attributes":{}` element is not part of the type `SF_M20_ProductOptions`. Somehow I need to avoid it during deserialization.

I am trying like this

```
List<SF_M20_ProductOptions> obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SF_M20_ProductOptions>>(doc);
```

Exact value of doc (doc.toString()) is

```
"\"[{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"M2O_ProductOptions__c\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/M2O_ProductOptions__c/aAP8A0000004ZkiWAE\\\"},\\\"Id\\\":\\\"aAP8A0000004ZkiWAE\\\",\\\"ExternalId__c\\\":\\\"722137_NCVB641\\\",\\\"Product__r\\\":{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Product2\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Product2/01t8A000005vdmtQAA\\\"},\\\"ProductCode\\\":\\\"722137\\\"},\\\"Option__r\\\":{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Product2\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Product2/01t8A000004f9FtQAI\\\"},\\\"ProductCode\\\":\\\"NCVB641\\\"}}]\""
```

Comment: On the json you have `Option__r` but the name of the Property is `MyProperty`
You have the correct name of the property either on the json or in the class

Comment: Are you using Json.Net or System.Text.Json or other?

Comment: @Camadas, Thanks for pointing that out. I have corrected it but still, the issue persists.

Comment: @PeterCsala, I am using Newtonsoft Json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your json is a collection, so you have to deseialize it to collection

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

SF_M20_ProductOptions options = JsonConvert
                      .DeserializeObject<List<SF_M20_ProductOptions>>(json)[0];
```

or

```
using System.Text.Json;

SF_M20_ProductOptions options = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer
                            .Deserialize<List<SF_M20_ProductOptions>>(json)[0];
```

and fix Option__r property, you can use [JsonProperty] attribute if you want to have different c# property name

```
public class SF_M20_ProductOptions
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ExternalId__c { get; set; }
    public Product__r Product__r { get; set; }
    
    [JsonProperty("Option__r")]  // using Newtonsoft.Json
    [JsonPropertyName("Option__r")] //using System.Text.Json
    public Option__r OptionR { get; set; }
}
```

Update

your second json was twice serialized, it is better to fix the source, otherwise

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

var json2="\"[{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"M2O_ProductOptions__c\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/M2O_ProductOptions__c/aAP8A0000004ZkiWAE\\\"},\\\"Id\\\":\\\"aAP8A0000004ZkiWAE\\\",\\\"ExternalId__c\\\":\\\"722137_NCVB641\\\",\\\"Product__r\\\":{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Product2\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Product2/01t8A000005vdmtQAA\\\"},\\\"ProductCode\\\":\\\"722137\\\"},\\\"Option__r\\\":{\\\"attributes\\\":{\\\"type\\\":\\\"Product2\\\",\\\"url\\\":\\\"/services/data/v51.0/sobjects/Product2/01t8A000004f9FtQAI\\\"},\\\"ProductCode\\\":\\\"NCVB641\\\"}}]\"";
json2 = Regex.Unescape(json2);
json2 = json2.Substring(1,json2.Length-2);

SF_M20_ProductOptions options = JsonConvert
                      .DeserializeObject<List<SF_M20_ProductOptions>>(json2)[0];
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried it but still not working.

Comment: For me it says error in position 513, I have updated the exact string in the question. please refer to that.

Comment: Hi, that helped, serializing multiple time was the issue, so instead of serializing to string, i maintained Dictionary<string,object> type,  with that i am successfully able to deserialize the object to expected type.